# Change apache landing folder

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, slim

I am currently developing a small project in PHP,with the Slim microframework.
I have structured the app so that I have an 'app' folder and a 'public' folder,but I am struggling to make my apache server point automatically to the 'public' folder,when the user lands on the root domain.
I have tried the .htaccess way,but apparently,Slim does not get on very well with this,since it throws me its custom 404 error.

Please give me a helping hand.
Thanks

Comment: Can you share the contents of your vhost and htaccess?

Comment: If you're seeing _Slim's_ custom 404 page, you've correctly configured .htaccess/Apache to use the framework. You need to check your routes within Slim and make sure that the HTTP request you are sending matches a route you've defined.

Comment: This is what I have pasted into the htacess file:"RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]".  @HPierce,it is not my routes fault.When I open up the project in my browser,on the public directory,everything works just fine

Comment: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#documentroot